# Is there a text compression library for .NET?

Tags: .net, text, compression

I a looking for a library that can compress text. Not short string but rather pages. 
Is there any known library or opensource code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may take a look at [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) and/or [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx).

Comment: +1. And if you don't need error detection, you can also consider DeflateStream in the same namespace. It has about 200 bytes less overhead.

Answer (score 4):

.Net has a couple of classes built-in for compression/decompression, Gzip and Deflate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx

Example usage:
http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/09/compress-and-decompress-strings-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

there is SharpZipLib